What's the meaning of soutenu ?
There's this card I want to learn in Mosalingua.
It's written 'adorer (soutenu)'.
In this case, I don't grasp its meaning.

It means the choice of this word (adorer) is consistent with the higher register of the French language. As in https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#higher_register This register is called registre soutenu in French. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/registre_soutenu

Well, I wouldn't have imagined such an answer. But it makes sense. Thanks.

The usual translation is 'formal', although in that particular case, adorer is not necessarily formal.
Note that soutenu (lit. sustained, upheld) is opposed to relâché (relaxed).

Wesh, moi je kiffe le soutenu, c'est mon registre que j'adore.

@Frank N'y décèlerais-je pas quelque ironie ?

Sont-ce des vers que tu me lui veux écrire?

@Frank Azy ! ——
